# Multiple elements, padding and margins inside display: table-cell extends outside parent

Tags: css, css-float, margin, padding

I am using `display: table-cell` so that I can easily do `height:100%` the child elements inside to get 100% height.

The problem is that when I have multiple elements inside or padding or margins, the parent does not stretch and instead the contents poke through. Putting a `overflow: hidden` will not work as I need the children to fit inside the parent properly.

Mark up:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="subcontainer">
        <h4>title</h4>
        <div class="menu">
            <p>test</p>
            <p>test</p>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <p>content</p>
            <p>content</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
p{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

html{
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    background: white;
}

body{
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: red;
}

.container{
    height: 100%;
    display: table;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.subcontainer{
    display: table-cell !important;
    height: 100%;
}

h4{
  padding: 0;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  background: blue;
  margin: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.menu, .content{
    background: green;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    float:left;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 20px;
}

.content{
    background: purple;
    width: 400px;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZQFrM/

The poking through is due to increased height inside caused by the following:

- The existence of the `h4` on top of the other elements.
- Padding and margin on h4.
- Padding on `menu` and `content`.

What can be done to resolve this problem? I definitely want to use the `display: table-cell` as I need the children to be able to stretch vertically to fill the parent.

Answer (score 0):

you have to remove the `float:left` and `display:inline-block` from '.menu, .content' also you have to apply a `display:table-cell`. So both div can be align horizontally.

Here is the Code http://jsfiddle.net/kheema/ZBLY7/7/

Here is the CSS..

```
p{
    padding:0;
    padding:0;
}
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: red;
}

.container{
    height: 100%;
    display: table;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.subcontainer{
    display: table-cell !important;
    height: 100%;
}

h4{
  padding: 0;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

    .menu, .content{
        background: green;
        height: 100%;
        /*display: inline-block;
        float:left;*/
    display: table-cell;
        width: 200px;
    }

    .content{
        background: purple;
        width: 400px;
    }
```

Comment: But now, the table no longer stretches 100% vertically :(

Comment: check this updated fiddle link, I added more content on `.content` div. http://jsfiddle.net/kheema/ZBLY7/10/

Comment: Yea, but if you increase the height of the results viewport, you can see that the height of the content no longer stretches to fit the whole viewport.

Comment: will look at it ..need to go offline, its late night here.